# How to digitalize CT controller?

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I have created CT cascade controller which now needs to be implemented in bigger DT structure to add sensor connections etc.

My controller is based mostly on PIDs and a few MatLab functions, and it has been tested with CT dynamics model through series of simulations. Now, I need to connect it to the sensors to test it on a real model. The structure for receiving data from sensors is already existing and it's obviously in DT.

So, my question is how can I digitalize my controller? Is it just matter of using DT PIDs instead of CT ones as inputs will be DT? Or is there something more I should take into consideration?

Comment: Do you have the overall transfer function of the entire controller scheme?  Once you do that you can use the `c2d` command to find the transfer function in discrete time.  You can use the default sampling scheme of Zero-Order-Hold which is good for most applications.  However, you need to know the **sampling time** for the discretization.  Do you know this?

Comment: But do I need to know sampling time? I mean, I have the structure which provides data from sensors in DT, now that data will be used as inputs to my controller, and then the outputs of that controller will be fed to the real model. It's just the controller itself has been tested in CT system, with dynamics equations connected to it (simulating the real model).